# What the return type means in (*Read)(void *p, void *buf, size_t *size);

Tags: c, pointers, visual-studio-2013, void, return-type

I'm working on an existing project using VS 2013 and c.

i came to this function but i haven't understand what it means :

```
  int (*Read)(void *p, void *buf, size_t *size);
```

What i know is it's a function that return pointer to int but i want to know :

> 1. Why void as type means when dealing with parameters (maybe a generic pointer ?)
> 2. What (*Read) means in this case (i think it's a cast !)

to really know what i'm using here is the complete dependencies :

```
typedef struct
{
  #ifdef USE_WINDOWS_FILE
  HANDLE handle;
  #else
  FILE *file;
  #endif
} CSzFile;

typedef struct
{
  int (*Read)(void *p, void *buf, size_t *size);
} ISeqInStream;

typedef struct
{
  ISeqInStream s;
  CSzFile file;
} CFileSeqInStream;

 CFileSeqInStream inStream;
```

The final objectif is to open a file but why all this complications !

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a cast, it's a *declaration*, and declares `Read` to be a pointer to a function taking some arguments and returning an `int`.

As for the first question, if you mean `void` as in `void *`, then that's a generic pointer, meaning you can pass any kind of pointer as an argument.

Answer (score 6):

> What i know is it's a function that return pointer to int

No, it's **a pointer to a function** that takes the following argument types as input:

- The type of the 1st argument: `void*`
- The type of the 2nd argument: `void*`
- The type of the 3rd argument: `size_t*`

And returns an `int` value as output.

Comment: the why all this complications if we want just to open a file as i think

Comment: @Frankenstein: You can implement different functions of the same prototype, set the variable `Read` to point to any one of them, and use it in order to call them. It is mostly used as a callback mechanism, where you want the user to supply their own function to be called at the end of some operation.

Answer (score 2):

It is a function pointer which will points to a function, which will take the arguments `(void *p, void *buf, size_t *size)` and return the value as `int`.

It is not a cast.

Answer (score 2):

It is the definition of a function pointer called read, which returns an int.

The parameters are a pointer p of type void,  a pointer buff also off type void and an int, probably the size of the buff argument.

I don't have the doc, but I guess it reads from p and returns the result in the buffer. The size argument is too avoid buffer overflows, and the return values the number of items read.

You can use the function by using the variable Read as a function: Read(), even if it is actually a pointer to a function (at least if the former has been imitialized).

Comment: but why it's of type void (for the parameter)

Comment: @Frankenstein the parameter type is `void *`, not `void`. Those stars are important

Comment: I guess it is because it can then function with different array types. *void can be a pointer to anything, so the function could work with *int, *byte, etc.